# CakePHP multiple OR conditions

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Im looking to create a simple query but i can't seem to figure out how to do it using Cakes conditions (cake 1.3), what im looking to do is quite simple, in SQL its just

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE firstvalue != '' OR secondvalue != ''
```

So basically only return row if there is a value in either firstvalue or second value.

At the moment i have;

```
$conditions = array(
    "NOT" => array(
        'firstvalue' => ''
    )
);
```

This works fine for the first value, but if i try and add anything to it, it still only returns the results for the firstvalue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to go about this:

```
$conditions = array(
    'OR' => array(
        array('NOT' => array('firstvalue' => '')),
        array('NOT' => array('secondvalue' => ''))
    )
);
```

Or, take advantage of the fact that "NOT a OR NOT b" == "NOT (a AND b)":

```
$conditions = array(
    'NOT' => array(
        array('firstvalue' => ''),
        array('secondvalue' => '')
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add multiple fields in OR condition, you have to write the fields in array.

Like,

```
$conditions = array(
    "OR" => array(
        "NOT"=>array('firstvalue' => ''),
              array('secondvalue'='')
    )
   )
);
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: This seems to return results that only have both values being empty, that would make the select statement a AND not an OR

Comment: As written, this will return things where the first is NOT blank or the second IS blank. That's not what the OP asked for. And be careful about simply adding a NOT on the second condition, as this will cause a key collision and only the second one will be retained.